# JQuery Tool Tip Selected Nested Div for Display Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a list of information around 30-50 rows each one requiring their own unique tool tip. I know I could make these all unique IDs but that would be a lot of wasted javascript. I am trying to have jquery return the tooltip of the nested `<DIV>` with the class of "show_tooltip" inside any `<DIV>` with the class of "tool_tip". All the tool tips will be unique.

```
<DIV class="tool_tip">
<DIV>Content here</DIV>
<DIV style="display:none;" class="show_tooltip">Any tool tip information goes here with possible html</DIV>
</DIV>

<DIV class="tool_tip">
<DIV>Content here</DIV>
<DIV style="display:none;" class="show_tooltip">Another but different tool tip to be displayed</DIV>
</DIV>
```

I have tried the following script but it always returns the first `<DIV>` with a class of "show_tooltip" it finds and repeats that for every row. Here is the script I have tried:

```
$(".tool_tip").tooltip({
bodyHandler: function() {
    return $("div.tool_tip").children(".show_tooltip").html();
},
showURL: false
});
```

I am using the following tool tip plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

EDIT:

Thanks for the answer below. My resulting code that worked was:

```
$(".tool_tip").tooltip({
bodyHandler: function() {
    return $(this).find('.tooltip_content').stop().html();
},
showURL: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, or should be, relatively easy:

```
$('.tool_tip').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.show_tooltip').stop().fadeIn(500);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.show_tooltip').stop().fadeOut(500);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DVVNZ/).

The above jQuery (and the linked demo) uses: [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) (just for reference purposes).

Comment: Thanks I figured it would be something simple I was missing. Very new to JQuery & Javascript.